# Generate a 64 bit .so file of GDAL Library

Tags: android, android-ndk, .so

I used the GDAL Library in my application and it has been working properly. The Google play service announced that they upload only 64-bit compliant APK after 1st Aug 2019. So I rendered the project to 64 bit compliant. Unfortunately, there has some issue happened in GDAL library. they showing that no implementation for the gdal library(ie the .so file according to the ABI type). So I think the corresponding GDAL 64 bit were unavailable for this scope.
I have the .so file in armeabi folder which is 32 bit compliant. Then I switched to arm64-V8a compliant. After that I generate the build, the corresponding .so file is not there in arm64-v8a folder.
So my question is, How we can generate the 64 bit .so files from GDAL Library?
Note:
Normally I used 32 bit compliant APK and it has been running properly. According to the new requirement of Playstore I used 64-bit compliant APK and done a smoke testing,unfortunately they get crashed, the issue of this crash is that, I used a GDAL library,which has a .so files with respect to ABI type. so when I run in 64 bit, the error showing that no implementation found for GDAL.
Hence I used the apk analyzer to look the difference from 32 bit compliant. so I identified that there is no .so file related to arm64-V8a folder.
So I think we need to generate the 64 bit .so file for the GDAL Library.
Is there any solution to generate this
I here by adding the screen shots, see the lib folder
[32 bit compliant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V94Om.png)
[64bit compliant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoNud.png)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YckQ.png)`.so files inside armeabi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same troubles migrating some ARM-Android libraries from 32 to 64 bits.

In the case of GDAL, fortunately I could find pre-built 64 bits binaries:

https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps/tree/master/gdal-prebuilt

GDAL java bindings can be found in the `libs` folder. That is the `gdal.jar` file:

https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps/tree/master/libs

Comment: Thank you for the steps @lusitanica. can we generate the .so file by using this source code? I want 5 types of .so files from gdal library. 1. libgdalconstjni.so 2. libgdaljni.so 3. libogrjni.so 4. libosrjni.so 5. libproj.so

Comment: Sure, just take a look at the `gdal.mk` file. Don't forget your mentioned  `jni` files are all bundled in one `so` file in the link I've pointed. https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps/blob/master/jni/gdal.mk

Comment: unable to build the Application in android studio.It is showing that arm64 abi type is not supported for platform. Do you have any idea about this.  Following issue raised while taking build: "ABIs [arm64-v8a, x86_64] are not supported for platform. Supported ABIs are [armeabi-v7a, x86]."

Comment: I had no trouble rebuilding `gdal.so` but then I'm using `ndk-build` script instead of Studio. Try to tweak with `Android.mk`, and don't forget the scripts are targeting Android 21 API, https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps/blob/master/jni/Android.mk

Comment: Since you are most probably using Gradle: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#building_with_android_studio_or_gradle

Comment: Thank you @lusitanica for the help, let me try out this :-)

Comment: The .so files were generated with libgdal.so and libproj.so files and which belongs to 64bit. Now I tried to generate the remaining '.so' files, so I looked into the gdal.mk file  and changed the module name. Then after I added the appropriate code in the java class and build. Unfortunately, the build got an error "Android.mk *** missing separator. Stop. The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item". Do you have any idea to resolve this?Is this gdal.mk file is used to modify for generating required .so files.

Comment: In this case there are no remaining `.so` files. Everything is bundle in the same `gdal.so`.  Nevertheless, if you want to build them individually take a look at this `Android.mk` from another project. Particularly, the end of the file where is the Gdal stuff, https://github.com/nutiteq/advancedlayers/blob/master/jni/Android.mk

Comment: Thank you for the reference @lusitanica,  I can understood the way, but while I ran using ndk build, It is showing "jni/gdal/lib/arm64-v8a/libgdal.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
". Is this need 64bit libgdal.a file??? Do you have any idea???

Comment: Apparently you're using CLang compiler. I, and the project I referenced use GCC compiler, instead.

Comment: Yes, I got It :) Thank you for your Support @lusitanica

Answer (score 0):

> How we can generate the 64 bit .so files from GDAL Library?

You have to build the library from its original source code using Android NDK.

See:

- https://github.com/paamand/GDAL4Android
- https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid

Comment: Thank you for the reply @shizhen. I tried the mentioned way, but unfortunately doesn't generate the so file. The steps that I did using the command line, so I got error.:-(